# Is the strength of presynaptic stimulus on the postsynaptic neuron affected more by the dendrites, or the cell body?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

Is the strength of presynaptic stimulus on the postsynaptic neuron affected more by the properties of the dendrites & axon terminals, or the cell body & axon?

[image]

Two years ago [I asked a question here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56402/how-are-neurons-synapses-biased) and learned that neurons do have a bias, and that various factors affect that bias, and now I'm trying to learn more specifically, how much of the strength of the the strength of a synapse, i.e. the size of the effect of a presynaptic stimulus on the postsynaptic neuron is dependent on the properties of each individual axon terminal / dendrite terminal, vs how much is dependent on the properties of the axon or cell body.

And do the properties of each individual axon terminal / dendrite ending vary diversely, even among dendrites of the same neuron, or do individual dendrites and axon terminals of the same neurons typically have similar properties?

Comment: I think this question is far too broad. You are better off thinking about what actually happens in neurons postsynaptically rather than trying to think in terms of what's "more important"  A or B - that sort of question isn't really answerable.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the type of axon, of course.
In Axosomatic synapses the properties of dendrite is not important, but for Axodendritic synapses, the properties of post syn. dendrite is more important as the amplification and other processing happen there. However, Soma is much nearer to Axon hillock, so changes by Soma wouldn't be declined as the impulses won't. It may be depended on neuron properties itself and so that's wrong to generalise!